# How can I discover what package __main__ belongs to

Tags: python, python-3.x

suppose I invoke a script thusly

```
python -m some_package.script
```

Is there a way to programmatically identify that `__main__` belongs to `some_package`?

Obviously I can't rely on `__name__` because it's always the same value. I haven't figured out if I can rely on `sys.argv[0]` because there might be an arbitrary number of directories before I get to a `PYTHONPATH` variable.

Is there some way to discover the package to which a main script belongs?

Comment: They're called modules in Python, not packages.

Comment: When would it not be `some_package.script.__init__`?

Comment: What do you mean by "belongs to some_package?"  As far as I know, a python script "belongs" to a package solely by virtue of the physical position of its source file (or .pyc or .pyo) in a hierarchy.  There is no such concept as officially declaring membership in a package.  I don't know what you are trying to do here.

Comment: All of you are correct. In python a package is a directory with an `__init__.py` and a set of other python files. Those python files are modules. When I execute a module, I can check `if __name__ == '__main__'` and that tells me that the module is being run as a script (rather than imported). The question is, how do I check the name of the _package_ to which __main__ belongs?

Comment: @Barmar. the modules live in a package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's

```py
sys.modules['__main__'].__package__
```

Comment: It definitely works. What version of python are you using?

Comment: Nevermind. I screwed up my call. You're right. +1